# Jquery: dealing with a json response?

Tags: jquery, json

I am having trouble parsing the response from my app. Here is the call with my best guess at how to deal with the json coming back...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'houses.json',
  method: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (h) {
      $(h).each(function () {
        console.log(h.address);
      });
    });
});
```

Here is the response I am getting back from the server:

```
[{
  "house": {
    "address": "7 view st dunedin nz",
    "lng": 170.500908,
    "id": 3,
    "lat": -45.875059
  }
}, {
  "house": {
    "address": "26 brown st dunedin nz",
    "lng": 170.496236,
    "lat": -45.875834,
  }
}]
```

the best I can get is having it say undefined. Once. I am trying to set up a loop for creating markers for a google map.
I could use another pair of eyes.
Anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who contributed. You guys are amazing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `h` is an array, you need to go down the property chain, `h` is a collection of `house` objects which have an `address` property, so change it a bit, like this:

```
   $.each(data, function(i, h){
     console.log(h.house.address);
   });
```

Make sure to remove that extra loop around it, no need since there's only one array.

Here's a visual way to think of it:

```
   h       h.house           h.house.address
 [ {       "house":{         "address":"7 view st dunedin nz".....
```

Comment: `h` is the **index** of an element, not an element.

Comment: @Felix - Completely missed that when deleting the other, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you define the callback function as `function(h)` thinking, `h` is an object from the array. But it isn't, it is the **index** of the element.

Just leave the parameters and use `this` (points to the element):

```
$.each(data, function(){
     console.log(this.house.address);
});
```

or define both parameters:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
     console.log(element.house.address);
});
```

or access the array by the index:

```
$.each(data, function(h){
     console.log(data[h].house.address);
});
```

Nick already said, how you should access the properties.

---

Reference: [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the callback for `each` is the index, so you need two parameters:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'houses.json',
  method: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
      $.each(item, function(j, house){
        console.log(house.address);
      });
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can use the fact that the item is set as the context for the callback, so you can use the `this` keyword to access it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'houses.json',
  method: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
      $.each(this, function(){
        console.log(this.address);
      });
    });
});
```

The inner loop will loop through the properties in the object, which is only one. You can access the property directly instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'houses.json',
  method: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
      console.log(this.house.address);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'houses.json',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
       $.each(data, function(h){

               console.log(h.house.address);

       });
```

Note the `dataType: 'json',` and `console.log(h.house.address);` sections.

Comment: The OP already defines `datatype: 'json'` and your code would not work, because `h` contains the index of the element, not the element itself.

Comment: Just corrected, it should be `dataType: 'json'` and NOT `datatype: 'json',`